# React accessing components outside of the render function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have an application where I make an ajax request and then loop over the data and create a list of HTML components. What I'm trying to do now is assign onClick or ref values to them but I get the error "Only React owners can have refs".

Here's a snippet of the code:

( When the ajax request completes it calls render data, loops over the data and then sets the state of the dataHtml which defines where my list will appear. I'd like to reference the "MyComponent" components when an event happen but if I try to apply any type of ref or onClick to them it doesn't work because they're not within the render function. How can I access these components when said event happens? )

```
renderData(data)
{
    var html = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html.push(
            <MyComponent key={ i } />
        );
    }

    this.setState({
        dataHtml: html
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref="data">
            { this.state.dataHtml }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason for the error, but why not simply render the components in the render function instead? Storing components in the state is less common. You usually store *data* in the state.

Comment: @FelixKling I would like to do that, but the reason I did it this way was because I wanted to update the html whenever I made an ajax request so I figured the only way to do so would be to store it in the state. Am I approaching things in the wrong way?

Comment: You just store the Ajax response in the state. The component gets rerendered whenever the state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the html elements in state variable, store the api response (data) and create the ui elements dynamically inside render method.

Whenever we update the state value by setState, react automatically re-render the component and update the ui with new state values.

Write it like this, by this way all the ui logic will be inside render method only:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        /*
            ajax call and do setState once get the data, like this:
            this.setState({
                data: response
            });
        */
    }

    _renderElements(){
        return this.state.data.map((el,i) => <MyComponent key={i} />)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this._renderElements() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this looks like what I was looking for. I won't be able to test it until tonight but I understand what was wrong with my way

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 constructor()
{
 this..handleClick(i) = this.handleClick(i).bind(this);
}

handleClick(i)
{
.......
}

    renderData(data)
    {
        var html = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html.push(
                <MyComponent key={ i } onClick = this.handleClick(i) />
            );
        }    
      return html;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="data">
                { this.state.dataHtml }
            </div>
        );
    }
```